# What is the AsyncAPI yaml equivalent representation of a Map in Avro schema

Tags: avro, asyncapi

Trying to Map the data types supported in AsyncAPI to the ones available in Avro Schema.
We have a Data type available in Avro schema that is Map , trying to find a way to represent it in Async API Yaml. Can anyone please advice ?

Comment: a map in YAML is called a hash

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct equivalent in AsyncAPI to an Avro Map but you can encode a map as an `object` by using the `additionalProperties` validation keyword:

```
type: object
additionalProperties:
  type: integer
```

might correspond to an Avro `map<int>`.

For complex types, you can define a schema to represent the complex type and use a `$ref` instead of a `type` in the `additionalProperties`.

Comment: Yeah, agree with you. Also, I'd like to point out that AsyncAPI chose JSON Schema as the language to describe schemas. So it's not how AsyncAPI does it but how JSON Schema does it :)

Answer (score 0):

As above mentioned for complex types you can use additionalProperties: true

I will elaborate it furthermore

As you can see the 'json' may dynamic, we don't know the actual shape of it ,therefore we can use that one as below examples

> map< json>

```
type: object
additionalProperties: true
```

> map<map< json>>

```
type: object   
additionalProperties:
  type: object
    additionalProperties: true
```

> And also this additionalProperties: true is identical for
> additionalProperties: { } , if you want you can use that too , for
> additionalProperties to be false you can use additionalProperties: not
> : {}

but if you know the exact shape of json you can use it like this:

> map< json> offset={"x":{"id":"sss"}}

```
type: object
additionalProperties:
 type:object
  properties:
   id:
    type: string
```

So in here only id field is allowed